# Pulling Results from NDSolve within a Table

Tags: differential-equations, list-manipulation

I am still learning the intricacies of Mathematica. I have an NDSolve within which I am trying to vary a specific parameter (I understand that ParameticNDSolve is likely a more efficient tool--the results it is producing are physically incorrect, I am hoping NDSolve will allow for the correct solution). To do this, I have a Table on the outside of the NDSolve. The result is a table with interpolating functions. I need help figuring out how to extract these results from the table so that I can graph them.
Thank you for the help!

Note: Once I can extract values from this table I plan to build two more tables so as to vary additional variables (d and zH below).

```
P[r_, z_] := (2. r ((2 - (4 r)/((1 + r)^2 + 
             z^2)) EllipticK[(4 r)/((1 + r)^2 + z^2)] - 
       2 EllipticE[(4 r)/((1 + r)^2 + z^2)]))/(\[Pi] ((4 r)/((1 + 
           r)^2 + z^2)) \[Sqrt]((1 + r)^2 + z^2));
Zmaxreg = 15;
Zminreg = -Zmaxreg;
Rmaxreg = 54;
Rminreg = 0;

d = 0; 
zH = 0; 
pref = 1;
a = 4;

Clear[H2, H]
Quiet[
 Table[sol = NDSolve[
    {(*EQUATIONS *)
     D[H2[r, z], z] == -(zH2 + d)*H2[r, z]*(P[r, z]/pref )^a,
     D[H[r, z], z] == 
      2*d*H2[r, z]*(P[r, z]/pref )^a - zH*H[r, z]*(P[r, z]/pref )^a,
     
     (*INITIAL CONDITIONS*)
     H2[r, Zminreg] == 1,
     H[r, Zminreg] == 0
     },
    (*VARIABLES TO SOLVE FOR*)
    {H2, H},
    (*RANGE TO SOLVE OVER*)
    {r, Rminreg, Rmaxreg}, {z, Zminreg, Zmaxreg}
    ],
  {zH2, 1, 10^3, 10}
  ]
 ]

H2[r_, z_] = H2[r, z] /. sol[[1]];
H[r_, z_] = H[r, z] /. sol[[1]];

~~~~~
```

Comment: Please post a minimal working example.

Comment: Well, you already know there's a `Part` (`[[]]`), don't you? That's exactly what you need. Please check the document of it more carefully.

Comment: @xzczd I read through the documentation prior to posting and wasn't able to find the answer I needed. Are you able to elaborate on how exactly I would be able to pull out a single interpolating function from the table?

Comment: It's confusing to me you're having difficulty with `[[]]`. (Especially after seeing you claimed you know how to do that in MATLAB in comment below. It's similar in _Mathematica_. ) How do you understand the `sol[[1]]` in your code? You simply copy it from somewhere without understanding it? Anyway, observe the output of the following code: `solutionlist = 
  Table[NDSolve[{x'[t]==-y[t]-x[t]^2,y'[t]==2 x[t]-y[t]^3,x[0]==k, 
     y[0]==1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 1}], {k, 1, 7}]; solutionlist[[3]]`, then observe `solutionlist[[3, 1]]`, then `solutionlist[[3, 1, 1]]`, then `solutionlist[[3, 1, 1, -1]]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

P[r_, z_] := (2 r ((2 - (4 r)/((1 + r)^2 + z^2)) *
        EllipticK[(4 r)/((1 + r)^2 + z^2)] -
       2 EllipticE[(4 r)/((1 + r)^2 + z^2)]))/
   (π ((4 r)/((1 + r)^2 + z^2)) √((1 + r)^2 + z^2));
Zmaxreg = 15;
Zminreg = -Zmaxreg;
Rmaxreg = 54;
Rminreg = 0;

d = 0;
zH = 0;
pref = 1;
a = 4;

sys = {(*EQUATIONS*)
   D[H2[r, z], z] == -(zH2 + d)*H2[r, z]*(P[r, z]/pref)^a,
   D[H[r, z], z] == 
    2*d*H2[r, z]*(P[r, z]/pref)^a - zH*H[r, z]*(P[r, z]/pref)^a,
   (*INITIAL CONDITIONS*)
   H2[r, Zminreg] == 1, H[r, Zminreg] == 0};
```

Using [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)

```
Clear[H2, H]
Quiet[
  tab = Table[{zH2,
     NDSolve[sys,(*VARIABLES TO SOLVE FOR*)
      {H2, H},
      (*RANGE TO SOLVE OVER*)
      {r, Rminreg, Rmaxreg}, {z, Zminreg, Zmaxreg}]}, 
  {zH2, 1, 10^3, 10}]];

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Evaluate[{H2[r, z], H[r, z]} /. tab[[n, 2]]],
  {r, Rminreg, Rmaxreg}, {z, Zminreg, Zmaxreg},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {r, z}),
  PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["zH2 = ``", tab[[n, 1]]], 14],
  PlotLegends -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {H2, H})],
 {{n, 61}, 1, Length[tab], 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Using [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html)

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[sys,
   (*VARIABLES TO SOLVE FOR*)
   {H2, H},
   (*RANGE TO SOLVE OVER*)
   {r, Rminreg, Rmaxreg}, {z, Zminreg, Zmaxreg},
   (*Parameter*) 
   {zH2}];

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Evaluate[{H2[zH2][r, z], H[zH2][r, z]} /. sol],
  {r, Rminreg, Rmaxreg}, {z, Zminreg, Zmaxreg},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {r, z}),
  PlotLegends -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {H2, H})],
 {{zH2, 601}, 1, 1000, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response! That is helpful.

What I'm still not sure about is how to access a specific cell within the table instead of all of them at once. For example, say that I would like to pull only H2 for zH2 = 200. In MatLAB, that would be a simple matter of understanding the shape of the matrix that the data is stored in and calling it. I'm struggling to find the equivalent operation in Mathematica.